# Is the Fast of Tevet considered a 24 hour fast?

Tags: zemanim, fast-days, evening-night

Is the Fast of Tevet considered a 24 hour fast, or does it begin in the morning until early evening?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! You might want to consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. Also, unless you have some special affinity with the number 8670, you might want to choose a more recognizable username. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only Yom Kippur and Tisha b'Av are 25-hour fasts.  The others are minor fasts, from dawn (first light, before sunrise) until nightfall (full dark).  The minor fasts are:

- Fast of Gedaliah (3 Tishrei)
- 10 Tevet
- Fast of Esther (13 Adar)
- Fast of the Firstborn (for those to whom it applies) (14 Nisan)
- 17 Tamuz

You can read more about these fasts at [Judaism 101](http://www.jewfaq.org/holidaye.htm).

Comment: +1. For some discussion about theoretically fasting from the nighttime, see [this related question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20278/has-anyone-declared-a-time-of-oppression-regarding-the-four-temple-fasts).